# String to BigDecimal, which one is good approch

Tags: java

I am trying to convert string to BigDecimal. Please tell which one is below is good approch

```
BigDecimal selAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
String amount = "1234";
selAmount = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(amount));
```

or

```
selAmount = new BigDecimal(amount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the first approach. If the string represents a value which can't be exactly represented by a `double`, you'll get accuracy issues.

You can't use the second approach either, since there is no overload of `BigDecimal.valueOf` which accepts a String.

So, option 3:

```
BigDecimal selAmount = new BigDecimal(amount);
```

Comment: Are you sure BigDecimal.valueOf() accepts string??. I am getting error on the same line.

Comment: Oh, OK. Must be `new BigDecimal` then. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass string directly to the constructor of [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

`BigDecimal.valueOf(double));` calls  `return new BigDecimal(Double.toString(val));` implicitly. So, your second case would be more efficient, and as Thilo says, more *correct*.

Code :

```
 */
public static BigDecimal valueOf(double val) {
    // Reminder: a zero double returns '0.0', so we cannot fastpath
    // to use the constant ZERO.  This might be important enough to
    // justify a factory approach, a cache, or a few private
    // constants, later.
    return new BigDecimal(Double.toString(val));
}
```

Comment: Not only more efficient, Double.parseDouble will lose precision (and maybe cannot even parse very big numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is better to proceed with, simply pass the string to the constructor of BigDecimal. The first approach may have precision issues.

From [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)) has

> **public BigDecimal(String val)**
>
> Translates the string representation of a BigDecimal into a
>   BigDecimal. The string representation consists of an optional sign,
>   '+' ( '\u002B') or '-' ('\u002D'), followed by a sequence of zero or
>   more decimal digits ("the integer"), optionally followed by a
>   fraction, optionally followed by an exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Passing string as a constructor is better way. You will lose precision in the first case.

e.g

> String s = "123";
>   BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(s);